# Datatable generate custom footer outside default div

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to generate datatable footer in a "article" tag instead of "div" and i don't know how to perform that using param sDom.

Code expected :

```
<article>
   <table id="datatable">
   //datatable content 
   </table>
</article>

//datatable footer
    <article class="pg">
      <div class="pg_count">
        <p><span>100</span> sites</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pg_std">
        <ul class="pg_std_list">
          <li><a href="#">Premier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Préc.</a></li>
          <li class="num sel"><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li class="num"><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li class="num"><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Suiv.</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dernier</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Is it possible?